# Next: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error with "use client" annotation"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

When I use ThreadCard component as a server component, it works, but when i change client component, this error message shows up:

[image]

Home Server component:

```
import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import { fetchPosts } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
export default async function Home() {
  const user = await currentUser();
  const result = await fetchPosts(1, 30);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="head-text head-left">Home</h1>
      <section className="mt-9 flex flex-col gap-10">
        {result.posts.length === 0 ? (
          <p className="no-result">No threads found</p>
        ) : (
          <>
            {result.posts.map((post) => (
              <ThreadCard
                key={post._id}
                id={post._id}
                currentUserId={user?.id || ""}
                parentId={post.parentId}
                content={post.text}
                author={post.author}
                community={post.community}
                createdAt={post.createdAt}
                comments={post.children}
              />
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
"use client"
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import { formatDateString } from "@/lib/utils";
import DeleteThread from "../forms/DeleteThread";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  currentUserId: string;
  parentId: string | null;
  content: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    id: string;
  };
  community: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
  } | null;
  createdAt: string;
  comments: {
    author: {
      image: string;
    };
  }[];
  isComment?: boolean;
}

function ThreadCard({
  id,
  currentUserId,
  parentId,
  content,
  author,
  community,
  createdAt,
  comments,
  isComment,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <article
      className={`flex w-full flex-col rounded-xl ${
        isComment ? "px-0 xs:px-7" : "bg-dark-2 p-7"
      }`}
    >
      <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
        <div className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-row gap-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id}`} className="relative h-11 w-11">
              <Image
                src={author.image}
                alt="user_community_image"
                fill
                className="cursor-pointer rounded-full"
                priority
              />
            </Link>

            <div className="thread-card_bar" />
          </div>

          <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
            <Link href={`/profile/${author.id}`} className="w-fit">
              <h4 className="cursor-pointer text-base-semibold text-light-1">
                {author.name}
              </h4>
            </Link>

            <p className="mt-2 text-small-regular text-light-2">{content}</p>

            <div className={`${isComment && "mb-10"} mt-5 flex flex-col gap-3`}>
              <div className="flex gap-3.5">
                <Image
                  src={`/assets/heart-${false ? "filled" : "gray"}.svg`}
                  alt="heart"
                  width={24}
                  height={24}
                  className="cursor-pointer"
                  priority
                />

                <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
                  <Image
                    src="/assets/reply.svg"
                    alt="heart"
                    width={24}
                    height={24}
                    className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                    priority
                  />
                </Link>
                <Image
                  src="/assets/repost.svg"
                  alt="heart"
                  width={24}
                  height={24}
                  className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                  priority
                />
                <Image
                  src="/assets/share.svg"
                  alt="heart"
                  width={24}
                  height={24}
                  className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                  priority
                />
              </div>

              {isComment && comments.length > 0 && (
                <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
                  <p className="mt-1 text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
                    {comments.length} repl{comments.length > 1 ? "ies" : "y"}
                  </p>
                </Link>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <DeleteThread
          threadId={JSON.stringify(id)}
          currentUserId={currentUserId}
          authorId={author.id}
          parentId={parentId}
          isComment={isComment}
        />
      </div>

      {!isComment && comments.length > 0 && (
        <div className="ml-1 mt-3 flex items-center gap-2">
          {comments.slice(0, 2).map((comment, index) => (
            <Image
              key={index}
              src={comment.author.image}
              alt={`user_${index}`}
              width={24}
              height={24}
              className={`${index !== 0 && "-ml-5"} rounded-full object-cover`}
              priority
            />
          ))}

          <Link href={`/thread/${id}`}>
            <p className="mt-1 text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
              {comments.length} repl{comments.length > 1 ? "ies" : "y"}
            </p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}

      {!isComment && community && (
        <Link
          href={`/communities/${community.id}`}
          className="mt-5 flex items-center"
        >
          <p className="text-subtle-medium text-gray-1">
            {formatDateString(createdAt)}
            {community && ` - ${community.name} Community`}
          </p>

          <Image
            src={community.image}
            alt={community.name}
            width={14}
            height={14}
            className="ml-1 rounded-full object-cover"
            priority
          />
        </Link>
      )}
    </article>
  );
}

export default ThreadCard;
```

I'm trying to change ThreadCard component client side, because I want to add framer motion or click event which I can only do client side.